# Chrome Devtools: Can I customize the information while inspecting on mouse over

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

As the picture shows, I can quickly inspect CSS properties like Color, Font and Margin.

Can I customize it to properties I want to see, for example: font-size, line-height...etc?

[inspect on mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJFKW.jpg)

Comment: No, it's hardcoded. You can only disable all the details altogether in devtools config.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for answering!  Sad to hear about it :(